# How to put a comma separated value to a numpy cell

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, rasterio

I have the georeferenced image with coordinates values like (475224.0, 4186282.0).The dimension of my image is (647, 2180). ie there are 647 columns and 2180 rows. I would like to take the coordinate values into a numpy array with size (647, 2180), so that I will get the coordinates of each pixel as an array. I code like below.

```
rr = rasterio.open(fname) #fname is the georefered image
col = rr.width
row = rr.height
coord = np.empty(shape=(col,row),dtype=rr.dtypes[0])

for i in range(0,col):
    for j in range(0,row):
        coord[i,j] = rr.transform*(i,j)
```

The problem is rr.transform*(i,j) will give values like (475224.0, 4186282.0). How to save it into a cell. For the above program, I'm getting error like below

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2881, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 3, in 
>       coord[i,j] = rr.transform*(i,j) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "comma separated value"? Is it a `tuple`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `rr.transform*()` output is a valid Python `tuple` I think you are doing this a bit more complicated than it has to be. By default, `numpy` will handle tuples and lists equal when creating and/or assigning to `np.array`:s. Thus, a much simpler solution for you, would be to just add an extra dimension and assign your values directly:

```
rr = rasterio.open(fname) #fname is the georefered image
col = rr.width
row = rr.height
coord = np.empty(shape=(col,row,2)

for i in range(0,col):
    for j in range(0,row):
        coord[i,j] = rr.transform*(i,j)
```

As you can see, the only difference is that I add extra dimensions to fit the size of `rr`. Here I have hard coded the third dimension to `2`. It is probably possible to find that dynamically, from the `rr` object instead. In the general case we are not limited to a `tuple`of two values.